# Button to return to Intent

Tags: java, android

I have the following sequence of pages:

```
-MainActivity
-Intent(Select a picture)
-DadosActivity
```

In MainActivity I have a button to open an intent for the user to select a photo, with the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

if (i.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

    startActivityForResult(i, SELECAO_GALERIA);

}
```

In this intent, the user will select a photo and after this is sent that selected item to another page, through this code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == MainActivity.this.RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap image = null;

        try {

            switch (requestCode) {

                case SELECAO_CAMERA:

                    image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    break;

                case SELECAO_GALERIA:

                    Uri localImagemSelecionada = data.getData();

                    image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), localImagemSelecionada);

                    break;

            }

            if (image != null) {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
                byte[] dadosImagem = baos.toByteArray();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DadosPostagemActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("fotoEscolhida", dadosImagem);
                startActivity(i);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

In the last activity, DadosActivity, the user can make some changes in the image, but my problem is when pressing the button on the back of the device and / or the toolbar, with the following code:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_dados);
toolbar.setTitle("Adicione uma descrição");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

According to what I did on AndroidManifest

```
<activity
android:name=".activity.DadosPostagemActivity"
android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
```

Activity is returning to MainActivity, but I wanted to press it to return to the intent and to choose the image again.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this, so that instead of returning to MainActivity, back to the intent so that he can choose the image again?

Comment: you need to show code..... not images of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone, I I found the solution was to just overwrite the method onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

Use the Codes Below.. 
In Manifest.xml file change code of AddPhoto Activity and AddDescription Activity like this-

This is for Addphoto Activity

```
<activity android:name=".AddPhoto"
        android:label="Add Photo"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

This is for AddDescription Activity

```
<activity android:name=".AddDescription"
        android:label="Add Description"
        android:parentActivityName=".AddPhoto">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".AddPhoto" />
    </activity>
```

Now your problems are solved. In the code we declared that Addphoto activity is a child of Main Activity and AddDescription Activity is a child of Addphoto Acitivity.

Change the AddPhoto and AddDescription with your own activity name.

Best of Luck.

Comment: That would solve my problem if AddPhoto was an activity, but addPhoto is a "Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" .

Comment: In that case you can use That Intent in onBackPressed method on the Description Activity..

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think what java code is necessary, my problem is to make a button go back to an "Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" I need only the code or somehow to do this

Comment: Just Use that Intent in onBackPresssed() Method in the description Activity.